# How to construct an isomorphism between $ \ker g^{\ast}$ and $~coker~ g$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $g: L \to M$ a linear transforming. $M, L$ finite dimensional.
$g^{\ast} : M^{\ast} \to L^{\ast}$
How do I construct an isomorphism between $ \ker g^{\ast}$ and $coker~ g$?
I really don't know what choose to build this isomorphism.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, I will edit.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I did it.

Comment: The result is a corollary to the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra). We have $coker(g)\cong \ker (g^*)$ and $im(g^*)\cong coim (g)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde how to adaptat to this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by constructing a pairing between the two spaces, and then show that it's non-degenerate.  I think you need to assume the vector spaces are finite-dimensional for the claim to hold.

Comment: I don't know what means construct a pairing between these two spaces. I corrected about the dimension that is required be finite.

Comment: Show how to interpret each element of $\ker(g^*)$ as a linear functional on $\mathrm{coker}(g)$.

Comment: I will try, thanks!

Comment: thank you! I I have followed your hint.